# Accessing the script of package.json of a npm package from our project package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I created a tool and registered it on npmjs.com named Yattex. It script looks something like this

`

```
"scripts": {
    "clean:reports": "rm -R -f cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports/mochareports ",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json",
    "generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/mochareports -- inline",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "yattex-tool": "node yattex-tool",
    "decorator": "node yattex-tool/test-decorators",
    "test": "npm run decorator && npm run scripts || npm run posttest || npm run yattex-tool"
  },
```

`

Now, in another project i installed the package and now i dont know what to write in scrips(test) to run the above test command which is in the node_modules/yattex/package.json file

I tried yattex and node node_modules/yattex/package.json

But it doesn't work. I'm a newbie and i cant find any solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you add a property

```json
"workspaces": ["./node_modules/yattex"]
```

to the `package.json` file in your other project, then `npm test --workspaces` will execute the tests both in your other project and in the `yattex` project (which is a "workspace" as explained on the `npm help run` page).

If you want to run *only* the tests for `yattex`, use `npm test --workspace=./node_modules/yattex`.

Comment: from my project i only want to run the test command from yattex/package.json file

Comment: i dont want to run both of them, as running the one in yattex/package.json will do all the work

Comment: See my augmented answer.